is there a way in oracle plsql to return a list of numbers for a dynamic in clause?
Here is what I have so far:
FUNCTION get_ids_by_acct(acct_p NUMBER) RETURN SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST
IS

CURSOR cli_cur
IS
  SELECT id
    FROM test_clients
   WHERE account = acct_p;
     
ids_n SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST := SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST();
cnt_n NUMBER := 0;

BEGIN

FOR cli IN cli_cur LOOP
  ids_n.EXTEND;
  ids_n(ids_n.COUNT) := cli.id;
  cnt_n := cnt_n + 1;
END LOOP;

IF cnt_n = 0 THEN
  ids_n.EXTEND;
  ids_n(conts_n.COUNT) := -1;
END IF;

RETURN ids_n;

END;

I have the following function that works just fine when I call it like this:
   SELECT *
     FROM test_clients 
    WHERE id IN (SELECT * FROM TABLE(get_ids_by_acct(1)));

but I would like the same result by doing the following:
   SELECT *
     FROM test_clients 
    WHERE id IN (get_ids_by_acct(1));

is this possible?

SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST is a VARRAY and does not support the MEMBER OF operation but if you create a nested table collection:
CREATE TYPE number_list IS TABLE OF NUMBER;

and you can simplify your function and use the user-defined collection:
CREATE FUNCTION get_ids_by_acct(acct_p NUMBER) RETURN NUMBER_LIST
IS
  v_ids NUMBER_LIST;
BEGIN
  SELECT id
  BULK COLLECT INTO v_ids
  FROM test_clients
  WHERE account = acct_p;

  IF v_ids.COUNT = 0 THEN
    v_ids.EXTEND;
    v_ids(1) := -1;
  END IF;

  RETURN v_ids;
END;
/

Is it really necessary to add -1 if there are no results? Would an empty collection not work just was well?
Then you can use:
SELECT *
FROM   test_clients 
WHERE  id MEMBER OF get_ids_by_acct(1);

Which, for the sample data:
CREATE TABLE test_clients (id, account) AS
SELECT 1, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 6, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 7, 2 FROM DUAL;

Outputs:



ID
ACCOUNT




1
1


3
1


6
1



fiddle

I noticed that the member of clause is significantly slower than selecting all from a table of numbers. Is there any optimization techniques for member of clauses?

@AndrewJudd Please see my update

@AndrewJudd I would consider whether it is more performant to do it without the function using something like: SELECT id, account FROM (SELECT c.*, COUNT(CASE WHEN account = 1 THEN 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY id) AS num_acct FROM test_clients c) WHERE  num_acct > 0 fiddle

Try Multiset Conditions, i.e. this one:
SELECT *
FROM test_clients 
WHERE id MEMBER OF get_ids_by_acct(1);

BTW, you can optimize your function by doing
CREATE TYPE number_list IS TABLE OF NUMBER;

FUNCTION get_ids_by_acct(acct_p NUMBER) RETURN number_list
IS

   ids_n number_list;
BEGIN
   SELECT id
   BULK COLLECT INTO ids_n 
   FROM test_clients
   WHERE account = acct_p;

   if conts_n.COUNT = 0 then
      ids_n := number_list(-1);
   end if;   
   RETURN ids_n;
END;

Update
I never use SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST, thus I was not aware this is a VARRAY. Answer from MT0 is correct.
Regarding your optimization: Yes, you can use the (undocumented) CARDINALITY hint. Problem is, you cannot use variables in hints, thus you need dynamic SQL. Assuming the number of returned records is similar to the size of nested table, it would be like this:
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 
   'SELECT /*+ cardinality( t '||get_ids_by_acct(1).COUNT||') */  *
   FROM test_clients t
   WHERE id MEMBER OF :nt'
BULK COLLECT INTO ... 
USING get_ids_by_acct(1);

See also https://asktom.oracle.com/ords/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:3779680732446#15740265481549

VARRAYs do not support the MEMBER OF operator. You would need to use a nested table collection type.
